# My depth-fist search route-finder is incredibly slow

Tags: graph, shortest-path, depth-first-search

Is this simply inherent as the branching-factor for my state-graph is 4 (so at any stage in Iterative-Deepening it will be 4^k and be exponentially slower than before??)?

Or is there something I've missed??

Here is my DFS-method:

```
    /**
 * CONTAINS Deja-Vu checker!
 */                                                                                              
private static Node depthFirst(Node start, String goal, ArrayList<Node> visited, int depth)
{      
    //END-case
    if (start.getConfig().equals(goal)){
        return start;
    }
    else if (depth == 0){
        //IF DEPTH REACHED BUT NOT FOUND GOAL
        return null;
    }

    //main sequence
    ArrayList<Node> neighbours = start.getNeighbours();
    for (Node neighbour : neighbours){
        //Deja-Vu check
        if (!(visited.contains(neighbour))){
           visited.add(neighbour);
           //my version of linked list
           start.append(depthFirst(neighbour, goal, visited, (depth-1)));
           //FALSE-PATH DENIAL
           if (start.route != null){
                return start;
           }
        }
    }
    //false path
    return null;
}
```

This is contained inside my Iterative Deepening method:

```
    /**
 * ASSUMES limit is 1000
 */
private static Node IterativeDeepening(Node start, String goal)
{
    Node route;

    for (int depth = 1; (depth < 1000); depth++){               
        route = depthFirst(start, goal, (new ArrayList<Node>()), depth);
        if (route != null){
            return route;
        }
    }

    //if all routes are null
    return null;
}
```

Comment: So, the function of `Node.append()` is to set the instance's `route` member?  It would be more conventional in that case to name it `setRoute()`.

Comment: You perform up to 1000 iterations of your depth-first search, with different depths.  If you're trying to find a minimum-length path then there are better algorithms, such as Dijkstra's shortest-path algorithm, which do not need to be iterated.  Even just switching to a breadth-first search would be better.  In fact, if all edges / nodes have equal cost, then breadth-first search with culling of child nodes already scheduled for visitation is equivalent to Dijkstra's.